# Chi square distribution for feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, feature-selection

In one [paper on ML](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-28397-5_1) I read that chi square distribution is used to reduce the number of features. In that paper, features are words. That paper is related to **Sentiment Analysis**, so we have **"positive", "negative" and "neutral" category.**

- How to calculate chi square distribution in that case?
- In Python there is `scipy.stats.chisquare` which gives chi_square value and a p_value. What do we do then with these two pieces of information?
- What to do for example with word "good" as a feature?
- How to calculate chi square distribution, and what to do with that?
- What does it mean to exclude some feature from the set of features, because in that paper it is mentioned that we take n of them with top chi square.

I really don't know how to do it. If there is any paper or book or link to learn that, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways for feature selection. A very good read in [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-machine-learning-python/), to recap:

- Univariate Selection.
- Recursive Feature Elimination.
- Principal Component Analysis.
- Feature Importance.

**Chi-Squared test For Feature Selection** goes under the Univariate Selection method for non-negative features. My favorite explanation of chi-Squared in one photo taken from this [blogpost](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/feature_selection/chi-squared_for_feature_selection/) is:
[image]

As you can see `scikit-learn` has an [implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html) for feature_selection using chi2 (perhaps according to `scipy.stats.chisquare`) as was shown very briefly in the above-mentioned blog post.

If you want a more thorough explanation and details how test ranks features based on statistics according to chi2 distribution and p-value etc., and also how to build your own chi2 class for feature selection in Python see this great [post](http://www.handsonmachinelearning.com/blog/2AeuRL/chi-square-feature-selection-in-python). Obviously one can read about the basics of chi2 distribution and test in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test).